# How to have on-page comments in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, comments

Currently, if you enable threaded comments on Drupal, the user has the ability to click on "reply". This takes the user to another page where they can write the comment. I want this functionality to happen on-page. In other words, if they click "Reply", a comment box must drop open using JavaScript or Jquery.

First prize is if there is already a module available or some setting that does this that I am missing. Alternatively, I would assume the best way is to just include the code in the Template File of the comments being generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're looking for the [AJAX Comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) module

**Features:**

> Provides ajax comments to Drupal sites. Features:
>
> - Makes AJAX submits
> - Allows replies to comments on the actual thread page
> - AJAX comments deleting
> - Works with CAPTCHA
> - Cool jQuery sliding
> - views integration